# Putting a circle in a 2d grid using arrays, for loops

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

first question here. Im simply trying to put this circle I've created into this 2d array grid. The idea is that it becomes sort of an island.
Currently only the first few outputs matter, so ignore the particles and waterline with regular ints. It currently prints a grid, and a separate circle. Please help me put the circle in the grid. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int** makeParticleMap(int width, int height, int windowX, int windowY, int radius, int numParticles, int maxLife) {

    int** map = new int* [height];
    for (int k = 0; k < height; ++k) {
        map[k] = new int[width];
    }
    for (int y = (height - 1); y >= 0; y--) {//height of map
        cout << "\n";
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {//width of map   

            map[x][y] = 0;
            map[windowX - 1][windowY - 1] = 1;
            cout << map[x][y]; //creation of map on a 2D grid
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y <= 2 * radius; y++) {          //this loop creates the circle
        cout << "\n";
        for (int x = 0; x <= 2 * radius; x++) {
            float distanceCenter = sqrt((y - radius) * (y - radius) + (x - radius) * (x - radius));
            if (distanceCenter) {//>radius-0.5 && distanceCenter<radius+.5){
                cout << '*';
            }
            else {
                cout << 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return map;
}

int main() {

    int width, height, windowX, windowY, radius, numParticles, maxLife, water;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    cout << "Enter Grid Width:";
    cin >> width;
    cout << "Enter Grid Height:";
    cin >> height;

    cout << "Enter drop-zone x-coordinate (0 - <width>):";
    while (true) {
        cin >> windowX;
        if (windowX > width) {
            cout << "Dropzone cannot be outside the map,reenter:\n";
        }
        else break;
    }

    cout << "Enter drop-zone y-coordinate (0 - <height>):";
    while (true) {
        cin >> windowY;
        if (windowY > height) {
            cout << "Dropzone cannot be outside the map,reenter:\n";
        }
        else break;
    }

    cout << "Enter drop-zone radius (minimum 2):";
    while (true) {
        cin >> radius;
        if (radius<2 || radius>width || radius > height) {
            cout << "Radius cannot be larger than the map or is too small,reenter:\n";
        }
        else break;
    }

    cout << "Enter number of particles to drop:";
    cin >> numParticles;
    cout << "Enter max life of particles: ";
    cin >> maxLife;

    cout << "Enter value for waterline (40-200): ";
    while (true) {
        cin >> water;
        if (water < 40 || water >200) {
            cout << "Invalid water level,reenter:\n";
        }
        else break;
    }

    int ** map = makeParticleMap(width, height, windowX, windowY, radius, numParticles, maxLife);
    //Dropzone(windowX,windowY,radius);

    for (int k = 0; k < height; ++k) 
        delete [] map[k];
    delete map;
}
```

Comment: "Currently only the first few outputs matter, so ignore the particles and waterline with regular ints." Yeah that's not how reality works. 
Reality works better when the one with the question actually prepares a question (once) and doesn't expect each viewer to distill the fun parts from a blob. If you come up with a minimal sample you probably get more than snide remarks

Comment: Just to set a baseline for answerers, do you understand why you get a square and then a circle?